# Anonymous Class Refactoring Issue

Tags: java, websocket, java-8, functional-programming

I use `nv-websocket-client` lib to connect web socket url. I see some examples in the document to connect url as below,

```
private static WebSocket connectSocket() {
        return new WebSocketFactory()
                .createSocket("http://...")
                .addProtocol(8081)
                .addListener(new WebSocketAdapter() {

                    public void onTextMessage(WebSocket websocket, String message) throws JSONException {
                        if (!message.isEmpty()) {

                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(message);

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); ++i) {
                               // TODO : Method Invocation
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    public void onConnected(WebSocket websocket, Map<String, List<String>> headers) throws JSONException {
                        // TODO : Method Invocation
                    }
                })
                .addExtension(WebSocketExtension.PERMESSAGE_DEFLATE)
                .connect();
    }
```

anonymous class used, and i see there are two method `onTextMessage` and `onConnected`

i would like to use functional approach, and referred https://blog.codefx.org/techniques/getting-rid-of-anonymous-classes/ blog tried to refactor my code. My try as below,

```
private static WebSocket connectionSocket(){

WebSocketFactory socketFactory = new WebSocketFactory();
WebSocket webSocket = socketFactory.createSocket(connectionParameters.getWssHostName());
webSocket.addProtocol(connectionParameters.getProtocol());
//new FunctionalWebSocketListener(webSocket, ); 
//webSocket.addListener();
webSocket.addExtension(WebSocketExtension.PERMESSAGE_DEFLATE);
webSocket.connect();

return webSocket;

}

public class FunctionalWebSocketListener implements WebSocketListener {

    private final BiConsumer<WebSocket, String> textMessage;
    private final BiConsumer<WebSocket, Map<String, List<String>>> connectionMessage;

    public FunctionalWebSocketListener(BiConsumer<WebSocket, String> textMessage,
                                       BiConsumer<WebSocket, Map<String, List<String>>> connectionMessage) {
        this.textMessage = textMessage;
        this.connectionMessage = connectionMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextMessage(WebSocket websocket, String text) throws Exception {
        textMessage.accept(websocket,text);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(WebSocket websocket, Map<String, List<String>> headers) throws Exception {
            connectionMessage.accept(websocket, headers);
    }

    // rest of un-implemented method goes here
}
```

Couldn't proceed further, and stuck up and i wanted to extract two separate public methods and expose to other class.

Any help much appreciated?

```
//new FunctionalWebSocketListener( p1, p2 );  //  Not clear what consumer to be passed here. 
//webSocket.addListener();
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is. Are you asking how to create an instance of FunctionalWebSocketListener? As in `new FunctionalWebSocketListener((s, text) -> {...}, (s, headers) -> {...})`?

Comment: Basically wanna extract  onTextMessage and onConnected methods from anonymous class using functional approach and expose as public methods for access.

Comment: public methods of what? Post a code sample showing what you would like to do.

Comment: public void onTextMessage() {
 // get the response of onTextMessage method

}


public void onConnected() {
 
 // check if the connection is success
}

Comment: Those methods already exist. They are in your FunctionalWebSocketListener class. Edit your question, and tell what the problem is. See the end of the article you linked to: it ends up doing `new FunctionalValueListener<>(
  this::valueInvalidated,
  this::valueChanged)`, i.e. invoke the constructor of the listeer and passing it two lambdas (or method references in this case. So do the same thing.

Comment: Sure, i will edit my question JB Nizet, sorry for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205766/discussion-between-parrotjack-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: got the solution, thanks for your inputs.